# My dog is obsessed with "humping" another dog

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have a Boston Terrier. He's reasonably well socialised and play's well with most dogs. One of my friends dogs though recently came to visit and Fester (dog) went banana's for hours and would not stop trying to have sex with him (they're both boys). It went on for hours. In the end I had to separate them (festers bit's were looking sore).

**Why would he only do this with one other dog?**

He is un-neutered. The other dog didn't seem overly concerned, though I think he appreciated it when we seperated them.

After the other dog had left he spent the entire evening "snuffling" around the carpet. He still seemed quite excited/agitated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let me say I feel your pain, I have a Boston myself and he's more than a handful. He also has a tendency to humping other dogs, male or female, not all of them but enough of them that is annoying.

I hadn't found a way to stop him doing that, but today, on the doggie park, he was playing with another Boston that started humping him. The owner of this dog just called his name and said "stop it" and he stopped (at least for a few minutes). After talking to her what I learned is that she had taught her dog the "stop it" command, not to stop humping another dog.

I think that's the answer to a lot of behavioural problems, they have to reliably learn to stop whatever they are doing on command. I know this is easier said than done, but you can start teaching him with simple things and reward with a clicker or treats once they stop what they are doing on your command. After the dog learns that good things happens when he listens to you hopefully he will apply that principle to more and more areas of his life.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to accept this, I didn't notice it for a long time!

Comment: A lot of dog humping is also excitement, which is why you get female dogs who hump.